# Install additional packages in vscode dev container

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I am using vscode as an editor. Using vscode `ctrl`+`shift`+`p` to open up the command pallet and used "Dev Containers: Create Dev container" to create a development container, And it created only one file `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json` .

```
{
    "name": "Debian",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:bullseye",
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-from-docker:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/github-cli:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/go:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1": {},
        "ghcr.io/guiyomh/features/golangci-lint:0": {}
    }
}
```

But I would like to install few other packages like `jinja2-cli`  after installation of python/pip3 package mentioned in the features or may be install other OS related packages.

Where should packages should be specified ?

Comment: You can use [`"postCreateCommand"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container#_rebuild) to run your install commands.

Comment: I noticed postCretionCommand but I am curious,  If it is the expected way of doing/installing the pkgs ?

Comment: An alternative way is to make your own docker file.

Answer (score 1):

Check that this line is included in your devcontainer.json

```
"postCreateCommand": "pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt",
```

Then create a requirements.txt file on the same level as you .devcontainer folder (not inside of it, outside).

If you add a package name to the requirements.txt file, it'll be added to the devcontainer at build time.

You can see an example in [this pull request](https://github.com/data-to-insight/CIN-validator/pull/300) I recently completed which needed a new package and I had to add it to my devcontainer in the last commit.

Side note: You'll see that I also updated my poetry.lock file in a previous commit (using the `poetry add package-name` in the command line) because that project uses poetry for package management too. You don't need to do that if you aren't using poetry.